# ToolWindow doesn't seem to honor AppBar

Tags: c#, winforms, appbar

So, I have an application which registers an AppBar using the SHAppBarMessage winapi call, placing a new bar along the top of the screen, and preventing other applications from taking over that space, similar to how the system TaskBar (by default) at the bottom of the screen.

Everything works great -- UNTIL the user tries to maximize a window whose FormBorderStyle is set to FixedToolWindow or SizableToolWindow, in which case **the tool window gets tucked underneath the AppBar**(s). I've noticed that tool windows even get tucked under the system TaskBar (notice the red boxes on the bottom of the second screenshot) such that you then can't see the bottom of them, so I'm worried that it's just not possible to get tool windows to behave like normal windows, but thought I'd ask.

Here is a quick sample of an AppBar (not my code, but a recreates the problem. It's in VB unfortunately, but it's pretty straightfoward to just cut & paste into a form code).

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a32923fb-e953-4212-8db3-e2c90edea78e/change-the-working-area-of-a-screen?forum=vbgeneral

If you run that, then create another empty project with a Fixed/Sizable ToolWindow border style and try to maximize that, you will see the issue. In the screenshots attached, noticed the red boxes I put in the corners get partially hidden -- not honoring the AppBar screen space reservation.
[image]
[image]
NOTE: I am already handling the fact that full screen apps (like mstsc, full screen video, etc) will get tucked under my appbar as well, but in those cases, Windows itself sends a ABN_FULLSCREENAPP message to the window saying "hey, there's a full screen app going on" in which case I can hide my app. (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/abn-fullscreenapp) No such message seems to exist for tool windows it seems. That at least would be a workaround, but not ideal.

P.S.: I can't change the tool windows themselves, as these come from other applications, I'm hoping to find some way to get them to behave with my AppBar application better!